# SQL: Don't display anything unless all values match

Tags: sql, sql-server

So in this case I want to display every ID where the corresponding value is 1. However, in the case below where the ID is 4, I don't want it to display the 4's where the value is 1, I just want it to not show 4 at all. If I do a `WHERE value LIKE '1'`, it'll show me the two IDs of 4 where the value is 1. Is there a way to not show 4 at all? Thanks in advance.

```
ID:.......1...2...3...4...4...4...5
Value:....1...1...1...1...2...1...1
```

(This is on Microsoft SQL Server management studio by the way)

Comment: I'm not understanding your question, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you not want records where `ID` is 4, or you only want records whose `ID` is also 1

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the ids, then use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(value) = 1 and max(value) = 1;
```

Comment: Silly, but from this answer I actually think that I understood what OP had asked because question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

To add on Gordon's answer

I would add a count since it seems your data has multiple 1s in that case if you have two 1s you'd have it as both min and max

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(value) = 1 and max(value) = 1 and count(value) = 1;
```

You could also use

```
select id from t group by id having sum(value) = 1 and count(value) = 1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what OP meant. Though in all fairness, the question is not clear and the example provided can give the impression that he is only interested in ids with a single value.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
    select * from (values
        (1, 1),
        (2, 1),
        (3, 1),
        (4, 1),
        (4, 2),
        (4, 1),
        (5, 1)
    ) as x(ID, Value)
)
select * 
from cte
where ID not in (
    select ID 
    from cte 
    where Value > 1
);
```